# Programmatically invoke Organize Imports and save the file afterwards

Tags: typescript, visual-studio-code, plugins, async-await, vscode-extensions

What I'm doing is basically:

```
async function doItAll(ownEdits: Array<TextEdit>) {
    const editor: TextEditor = await getEditor();
    applyOwnChanges(editor, ownEdits);
    await commands.executeCommand('editor.action.organizeImports',
        editor.document.uri.path);
    await editor.document.save();
}
```

It all works, but the `save` happens *before* `organizeImports` finishes and I end up with a dirty editor, when the imports get modified.

I tripple checked that I didn't forget the `await` keyword, yet it works like it wasn't there.

This may be a bug or I may be doing or expecting something wrong. Am I?

Answer (score 2):

Indeed *organizeImports* command returns before it actually updated the document.

As workaround use **onDidChangeTextDocument** to intercept when *organizeImports* is finished and your doc is ready for save.

```
const handler = vscode.workspace.onDidChangeTextDocument(doc => {
  if (doc.document.uri.path === editor.document.uri.path) {
    doc.document.save()
    handler.dispose()
  }
})
```

Comment: I'l surely try your solution `onDidChangeTextDocument` (and I'd bet, it'll work), but isn't this early returning a bug?

Comment: Maybe you should make a small test extension within separate repo to reproduce.
I think it's something to do with underlying workspace.applyEdit code and language server communication.
If you want to dive in you can start from here: https://github.com/microsoft/vscode/blob/c4b6a6b537de49a734d0eedea06152ea37dfdb6a/extensions/typescript-language-features/src/features/organizeImports.ts#L55

Answer (score 0):

`executeCommand` is Thenable . So, the `save()` method should be moved inside thenable.

```
vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.organizeImports', editor.document.uri.path).then(function(){
        await editor.document.save();
});
```

If the save still happens before `organizeImports` finishes then try to call the save method inside `setTimeout(function(){....}, T)`.

```
 vscode.commands.executeCommand('editor.action.organizeImports', editor.document.uri.path).then(function(){
       setTimeout(function(){
            await editor.document.save();
       }, 500);
});
```

Comment: `executeCommand` returns a Promise (so, yes it's "thenable"), but this approach is not really any different to awaiting the promise instead of invoking its `.then` function.

Comment: I can't use any timeout as I need to open, organize, save and close a lot of editors without bothering the user for long.